# list float none combine with float left or right

Tags: html, css

I have the following `ul` tag in my HTML

```
<ul style="position:absolute">
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
    <li>
        list 4
        <p>list 4 content goes here</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

From that markup, I want to achieve the following layout.

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
| list 1    | list 4                  |
| list 2    | list 4 content goes here|
| list 3    |                         |
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

So far I am trying to give list 1 - list 3 `float:none` and list 4 `float:left`, but no luck..list 4 is placed at the bottom.

how to achieve it?

the CSS

```
ul.parent-menu>li>ul.sub-menu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #b6b6b6;
    border-top: 5px solid #b81d18;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul.parent-menu>li:hover>ul.sub-menu{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.parent-menu>li:hover>ul.sub-menu>li{
    float: none;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

ul.parent-menu>li:hover>ul.sub-menu>li.menu-item-has-children{
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

so, I want to `float:none` all `li`s that doesn't have `menu-item-has-children` class.

Comment: can u share the css with us?

Comment: now , the html does not match the css :\

Comment: the html http://codepaste.net/io64hq

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
ul li {
  float: none;
}
.list4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<ul style="position:absolute">
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li>list 2</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
  <li class="list4">
    list 4
    <p>list 4 content goes here</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

try this

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i can't use `left: 40%` since there might be more li floated right next to list 4

Answer (score 0):

css can be implemented at all tags,or
1.try to differentiate the li s,and the best practice is by applying a class attribute  or
2. create two separate ul s and apply different css float.